# What is causing "Mismatch of entities in the document" when running migrate:delta

Tags: magento2, magento-1.6, magento2-migration-tool

I have successfully upgraded a Magento 1.4.1 database to 1.4.2 and then to 1.6.0. I also successfully was able to **migrate:setting** and **migrate:data** from the 1.6.0 database over to my Magento 2.1.2 database. (Things were looking great!...)

I have since then been working on the 2.1.2 site; adding a new theme, changing some settings, and editing cms blocks. I did all this with the assumption that I could run a **migrate:delta** and bring over new customer and order data, as that is all I would really need to launch the new site. (I have not created any new orders or customers in the 2.1.2 database)

In my attempt to **migrate:delta** (after i run through the 1.4.1 -> 1.6.0 upgrade process again to get current live data) i ran into an error of missing the deltalog tables (with prefix m2cl*). I pulled those tables, *which were all empty*, from the first database that i migrated from. This allowed me to run a **migrate:delta** with the following warnings:

```
2017-01-25 23:32:29][INFO][mode: delta][stage: delta delivering][step: Customer Attributes Step]: started
[2017-01-25 23:32:30][INFO][mode: delta][stage: volume check][step: Customer Attributes Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[2017-01-25 23:32:30][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: customer_entity
[2017-01-25 23:32:30][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: customer_address_entity
[2017-01-25 23:32:30][WARNING]: Volume Check failed
[2017-01-25 23:32:30][INFO][mode: delta][stage: delta delivering][step: Map Step]: started
[2017-01-25 23:32:30][INFO][mode: delta][stage: volume check][step: Map Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_category_entity
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_category_entity_int
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_category_entity_text
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_category_entity_varchar
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_category_product
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_compare_item
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_entity
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_entity_datetime
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_entity_decimal
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_entity_int
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_entity_media_gallery
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_entity_text
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_entity_varchar
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_option
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_option_price
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_option_title
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_option_type_price
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_option_type_title
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_option_type_value
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_website
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: cataloginventory_stock_item
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalogrule
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: search_query
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: cms_block
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: cms_block_store
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: salesrule_coupon_aggregated
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: customer_eav_attribute_website
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: newsletter_subscriber
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: report_compared_product_index
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: report_event
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: report_viewed_product_index
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_bestsellers_aggregated_daily
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_bestsellers_aggregated_monthly
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_invoice
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_invoice_item
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_order
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_order_address
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_order_item
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_order_payment
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_order_status_history
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: quote
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: quote_address
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: quote_address_item
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: quote_item
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: quote_item_option
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: quote_payment
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: quote_shipping_rate
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_shipment
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_shipment_item
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_shipment_track
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_invoiced_aggregated
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_invoiced_aggregated_order
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_order_aggregated_created
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_order_tax
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_payment_transaction
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_shipping_aggregated
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_shipping_aggregated_order
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: salesrule
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: salesrule_coupon
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: salesrule_coupon_usage
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: salesrule_customer
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: tax_calculation
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: tax_calculation_rate
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: tax_order_aggregated_created
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: wishlist
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: wishlist_item
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Volume Check failed
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][INFO][mode: delta][stage: delta delivering][step: Log Step]: started
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][INFO][mode: delta][stage: volume check][step: Log Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: customer_visitor
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Volume Check failed
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][INFO][mode: delta][stage: delta delivering][step: OrderGrids Step]: started
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][INFO][mode: delta][stage: volume check][step: OrderGrids Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_order_grid
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_invoice_grid
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_shipment_grid
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Volume Check failed
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][INFO][mode: delta][stage: delta delivering][step: SalesIncrement Step]: started
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][INFO][mode: delta][stage: volume check][step: SalesIncrement Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch in last increment id of order entity
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch in last increment id of invoice entity
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Mismatch in last increment id of shipment entity
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][WARNING]: Volume Check failed
[2017-01-25 23:32:35][INFO][mode: delta][stage: volume check][step: SalesIncrement Step]: Migration completed successfully
```

I guess my question is a few questions:

- Is the approach I took a correct way to get data from 1.4.1 to 2.1.2
- Is there a missing reference that the **migrate:delta** is looking for
  since this updated database wasn't the original one I migrated from?
- and the title question.

Answer (score 0):

In your approach after successful setup of Magento 2 website, I mean migration of data on development and setup of complete theme and website is done. You need to migrate the fresh data from Magento 1 again and you can use the same codebase and your Magento 2 store with new data will be up. Please try to follow this approach.

Comment: @LRV, may I know how you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The "Mismatch of entities" error is caused by a difference between the count of source documents and the count of destination documents, of the same type.
If you look into the core code, this check is implemented in all the Volume.php of all steps.
For example

```
src/Migration/Step/Customer/Volume.php


 $sourceCount = $this->sourceRecordsCounter->getRecordsCount($sourceDocName);
 $destinationCount = $this->destination->getRecordsCount($destinationName);
 if ($sourceCount != $destinationCount) {
            $this->errors[] = sprintf(
                'Mismatch of entities in the document: %s Source: %s Destination: %s',
                $destinationName,
                $sourceCount,
                $destinationCount
            );
  }
```

Is it ok to go on with the migration with this mismatch warning? It depends on what you want, and what type of document has encountred the problem.
In my case it was ok, because I got this errors on eav attributes that I didn't need to migrate. I suggest to verify the actual result, and decide if it suits your needs, to decide if you can ignore those warnings. Otherwise you'll have to find out the reason, maybe playing with ignore and transform tags in the map.xml file.

About your question, if it is a good approach, I give you a feedback based on my experience.
The migration tool is a valid tool for migrating data and settings from Magento 1 to Magento 2, but it's a bit complicated, especially if you don't want to migrate everything (settings, EAV, ecc...).
In most of cases you'll have to implement some adjust/fix method after running standard steps. I had for example some issues on customer attributes. I think anyway that this tool is a good starting point